# Что означают числа -5 после запятой в форматированном выводе C# ( на примере)?

Tags: c#, вывод, формат

Что означают числа -5 после запятой в форматированном выводе C# ?

```
Console.WriteLine("{0,-5}\t{1,-5}\t{2}", pe32.th32ProcessID, pe32.th32ParentProcessID, pe32.szExeFile);
```

Comment: отступить 5 символов от конца

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это выравнивание.

> Optional. A signed integer that indicates the total length of the
>   field into which the argument is inserted and whether it is
>   right-aligned (a positive integer) or left-aligned (a negative
>   integer). If you omit alignment, the string representation of the
>   corresponding argument is inserted in a field with no leading or
>   trailing spaces.
>
> If the value of alignment is less than the length of the argument to
>   be inserted, alignment is ignored and the length of the string
>   representation of the argument is used as the field width.

[Документация.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx)

Само значение это количество символов в которое будет вставлено число, если число положительное то вставка идёт справа, а если отрицательно то слева.

Вот такой пример:

```
for(int i=0;i<10;i++) {
    Console.WriteLine("Hallow{0,5}hi",i);
}

for(int i=0;i<10;i++) {
    Console.WriteLine("Hallow{0,-5}hi",i);
}
```

И вывод:

```
Hallow    0hi
Hallow    1hi
Hallow    2hi
Hallow    3hi
Hallow    4hi
Hallow    5hi
...
Hallow0    hi
Hallow1    hi
Hallow2    hi
Hallow3    hi
Hallow4    hi
Hallow5    hi
...
```

Тестируем - https://ideone.com/N9wSIe